# Paypal Oauth2 Axios results in circular structure

Tags: json, post, axios, paypal

I'm trying to get a oauth token from the paypal sandbox using axios. The request looks like this:

```js
    const response = await axios.post(
        'https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token',
        new URLSearchParams({
            'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
        }),
        {
            auth: {
                username: process.env.PP_CLIENT,
                password: process.env.PP_SECRET
            },
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'Accept-Language': 'en_US'
            }
        }
    );
    console.log(`response: ${JSON.stringify(response.data)}`);
```

As far as I can tell this code used to work, because I used it before. However now I'm getting the error:

```
"Converting circular structure to JSON
   --> starting at object with constructor 'ClientRequest'
    |     property 'socket' -> object with constructor 'TLSSocket'
    --- property '_httpMessage' closes the circle"
```

I have confirmed that my credentials are correct by testing it with curl, which works and by copying it directly into the code. I've also tries fetch (which always yields an empty response)